# keydown event no longer returns key/code/keyCode etc. for password fields in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I used to be able to access `event.key` and/or `event.code` and/or `event.keyCode` and/or jQuery's standardised `event.which` for `keydown` events on password and text inputs.

As of writing, this still works in Chrome (71) but has stopped working in Firefox (65).

See fiddle:

```js
$('input').on('keydown', e => {
   $('pre').append("keyCode: " + e.which + " "  + e.key + " "  + e.code + "\n"); });
$('pre').append('type in box\n');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
<input type="password" >
```

On Chrome this outputs expected values, e.g.

```
keyCode: 68 d
keyCode: 83 s
keyCode: 18 Alt
```

On firefox this now outputs (regardless which keys are pressed):

```
keyCode: 229 Process undefined
keyCode: 229 Process undefined
keyCode: 229 Process undefined
```

Firefox does not behave this way if you change the input to `text`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) does not seem to make reference to this.

I've changed some of my code to use `keypress` for now, which seems to work still, but I'd like to understand why and if there's a way to do it with keydown/up.